# restore MySQL database from the file in background

Tags: php, mysql, database, nohup, command-line-interface

I know this topic has been discussing a lot of time. But I need help.
My aim is to **restore MySQL database from the file in background**

To make it from shell I use such script:

```
    nohup mysql --host=localhost --default-character-set=utf8 --user=root --password=dbroot my_databse_name < dump.sql 2> /dev/null & echo $!
```

And it works. This command restores my database from the file in background.
But when I try to put it into **PHP** file and call **shell_exec** my php script waits for the end of operation.
Here is a code (test.php):

```
   <?php
    $cmd = "mysql --host=localhost --default-character-set=utf8 --user=root --password=dbroot my_databse_name < dump.sql";
    $command = "nohup $cmd 2> /dev/null & echo $!";
    $pid = shell_exec($command);
    echo "If you see this message just after run script than it works properly";
    echo $pid."\n";
```

From CLI I run it as:

```
    php test.php
```

and I can not see debug message till mysql restore database from the file.

In parallels I manage MySQL with SHOW processlist;
Seems like restoration of database is working. But why I can not get PID of the process ?

Comment: Have a look at this link - http://php.net/pthreads

Comment: I am not sure server where I will use this script have Process Control Extensions :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using `exec()` function [explained here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Change `$pid` to:

```
$pid = exec('nohup $cmd 2> /dev/null & echo $!');
echo $pid."\n";
```

Give it a try!